# How to get the starred version of a latex section on org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

How do I get the starred version of a latex chapter/section from an org-mode headlight?

```
* my section      --->     \section{my section}
???               --->     \section*{my section}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it: I need to add the `unnumbered` property to the headline

```
* Section with number
Text of numbered section

* Section without number
:properties:
:unnumbered: t
:end:
Text of unnumbered section
```

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). It's a good thing to do that to make future visitors aware that the question had a satisfactory answer (at least for one person), so they can judge whether to try it themselves (and possibly thank you at that point by upvoting it :-)